# Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ with $\dim(\mathfrak{g}) = 3$ such that $\dim([\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g }]) = 1$

Tags: lie-algebras

**Problem**: Prove that (up to isomorphisms) exists a unique Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ with $\dim(\mathfrak{g}) = 3$ such that $\dim([\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g }]) = 1$ and $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]\subseteq Z(\mathfrak{g})$.

---

I don't even know how to start, I guess that is not too difficult but I need an initial guide.

Comment: I would start by finding a non-zero vector in $[g,g]$ and extending it to a basis of $g$.

Comment: Please avoid posting "I don't even know how to start". One can always start with some examples of $3$-dimensional Lie algebras, or have a look at MSE here. If you start doing something, then you have more context for posting where you got stuck.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you, I'll have it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers to get you started.

As a vector space $\langle z \rangle = [\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}]$ for some $z \in \mathfrak{g}$. Note that $z \in Z(\mathfrak{g})$ by assumption.

Extend to a basis $z,x,y$ of $\mathfrak{g}$. What can you say about the commutators between the basis elements?